# how to remove sound clipping in existing record

Tags: audio-recording, audio, signal-processing, filter, clipping

I have an old record that has some clipping effect that happened during recording. This is a song, so i can't just cut out all frequencies probably ... is there any smarter way around to get rid of that clipping?

http://www.2shared.com/audio/SMuu991E/smrad.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to repair clipped signal, since when clipping occurs, part of the original signal is eliminated and cannot be restored. The phenomena is described in the below image:
[image]

However there are few commercial clicks\pops removal apps available which could improve the signal. The following list of software appear in Wikipedia:

1. Sony Sound Forge
2. iZotope Rx2
3. Adobe Audition
4. Nero Wave Editor
5. plugin in the Audacity LADSPA package come with clip restoration software. There is also an Audacity plugin called Clip Fix

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually remove clipping - in recording your levels were too high so your waveforms were damaged at that point. Nothing can bring back the originals, andv even filtering can only be used to remove some of the frequencies that may have been caused.